# Can the input of a quantum circuit be a multidimensional array?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

Why is $|A\rangle$ (a column vector) often used as an input in many references? Is there a quantum encoding that can make the input a matrix of $A$ (an $n$ by $m$ matrix)? Then a new type of quantum gate is constructed to perform accelerated computation on the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good overview about the different methods that can be used to load a matrix into a quantum computer in [Quantum algorithms for data analysis](https://quantumalgorithms.org/chap-classical-data-quantum-computers.html) by Luongo.

Also, there is a chapter dedicated to one of these methods "Block encoding" in [Lecture Notes on Quantum Algorithms for Scientific Computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309) by Lin.